# PHP calculate between two time with H:i:s format

Tags: php

i'm trying to find and calculate between `startime`, finish time as: `starttime + 1 hour` and current time. if current time is between start and finish i must be print message such as `please try after 1 hour`:

```
$current_date_time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
$user_current_time = $current_date_time->format("H:i:s");

$start_limit_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime('2015-09-15 14:57:31'));
$finish_limit_time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($start_limit_time) + (60 * 60 * 1));

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $user_current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start_limit_time);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $finish_limit_time);
if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
{
    echo 'here';
}
```

this code is not correct and i can not fix that,

Comment: You are comparing DateTime-objects in your if.. Take a look at what you cando with [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Spend some time reading the document would be very helpful: [`strtotime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`DateTime::__construct`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) accepts [many formats, including "relative" phase](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), plus you can take advantage of [`DateInterval` class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) with [DateTime::diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, it shows the difference in minutes:

```
$current_date_time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
$user_current_time = $current_date_time->format("H:i:s");

$start_limit_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime('2015-09-15 14:57:31'));
$finish_limit_time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($start_limit_time) + (60 * 60 * 1));

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $user_current_time);
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $start_limit_time);
$date3 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $finish_limit_time);

if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
{
    $tryAgainIn = $date3->diff( $date1 );

    // just minutes
    echo "try again in ".$tryAgainIn->format( "%i minutes" );

    // or hours and minutes
    $hours   = $tryAgainIn->format('%h');
    $minutes = $tryAgainIn->format('%i');
    echo "try again in $hours hours and $minutes minutes";
}
```

For more information take a look at: [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: thanks sir. very useful tip for me such as `"%i minutes"`. can you complete code? your if does not work

Comment: the if depends on the time you actually have. to debug this try: var_dump( $date1->format( 'H:i:s' ) );
var_dump( $date2->format( 'H:i:s' ) );
var_dump( $date3->format( 'H:i:s' ) );

var_dump( $date1 > $date2 );
var_dump($date1 < $date3 );

Answer (score 0):

At first you should avoid operating with strings format, as they should only be used IMHO to printing and retrieving data from outside. Use only timestamp or OOP methods.

I believe, that this is something you are looking for:

```
$startTime = new DateTime('2015-09-15 14:57:31');
$endTime = clone $startTime;
$endTime->modify('+1 hour');


if ($startTime->getTimestamp() <= time() && time() < $endTime->getTimestamp()) {
    echo 'here';
}
```

I wonder why you need to use H:i:s format. Can you give some bigger picture?

---

Edit: Try this, as prior to now I did not fully understand what you want to do ;)

```
$origin = new DateTime('2015-09-15 14:57:31');

$startTime = new DateTime('today '.$origin->format('H:i:s'));
$endTime = clone $startTime;
$endTime->modify('+1 hour');


if ($startTime->getTimestamp() <= time() && time() < $endTime->getTimestamp()) {
    echo 'here';
}
```

Comment: Where did $a just come from, I think you mean $starttime?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: @Astinus Eberhard thanks. my current time is `14:24:00` and your if does not work

Comment: @AstinusEberhard for example debug your `if` is: `echo $startTime->getTimestamp(). '   ' . time(). '   '. $endTime->getTimestamp();` result: `1442329051 1442829358 1442332651`

Comment: Ok now I fully understand what you want to do ;)